# Issue in fetching records from database using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

The method shown below is not fetching data from db with the criteria strProductId. I'm getting the value of strProductId inside the method. Can anyone please help..Thanks in advance....

```
public List<ProductServices> getAllServices(String strProductId){
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(ProductServices.class);
        cr.add(Restrictions.eq("productId", strProductId));
        return (List<ProductServices>) cr.list();
    }
```

Comment: you tryto get the value of strProductId inside the method and  strProductId  is here param, thast is strange.

Comment: yes i'm getting strProductId from service layer as parameter but is there any mistake while giving criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do some thing like this

```
Session session = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx = null;
try {
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(ProductServices.class);
    cr.add(Restrictions.eq("productId", strProductId));
    return (List<ProductServices>) cr.list();
      tx.commit();
     }
   catch (Exception e) {
      if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
       e.printStackTrace(); 
  }finally {
  session.close();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Method `getAllServices` must be in a transaction. Check it, please.

**Updated**

You must open a transaction, do a request and close a transaction. It can be done  by Spring of course.
See this [example](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-with-hibernate-persistence-and-transactions-example). `UserManagerImpl` has a `@Transactional` annotation on methods.